# Do I need two SQL queries or can it be done in one? Check if username or email exist before registering user

Tags: sql

I'm using postgres, and I'm wondering if I need to check both username and email separately or if it can be done in one shot.

I'm just doing:

```
select username, email 
from users 
where username = 'some_username' 
    OR email = 'some_email'
```

Here I'll get some result and if the # of rows > 0, then either the username or email exists.  If I want to know whether username exists, or email exists already, do I need to do two queries?

I am trying to convey this information to my front end so the user can change either email or username..

Thanks

Comment: That'll do, but if you only want to know if it exists, a `count(*)` would be more convenient. And, be aware of SQL injections ;)

Comment: Thanks.  If I want to convey which one exists to the front end though, will I need two queries?  Also can you please explain more on the SQL injection?  This lookup will happen on my backend (node + express + pg) thanks

Comment: What database system do you use?

Comment: i am using postgres.

Comment: You don't need this test; both the conditions could be `UNIQUE` constraints. So, on any attempt to violate the uniqueness, the front end will notice...

Comment: I have them both as unique but just wanted to make sure :(

Comment: Also, if the query fails due to a unique constraint, you will not be able to determine what constraint was violated (i.e. what was the already existing part)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* indeed check not only if they both exist, but also which one matches in one single (ugly) query:

```
select 
    count(case when username = 'some_username' then 1 else 0 end) as users, 
    count(case when email = 'some_email' then 1 else 0 end) as emails
from users 
where username = 'some_username' 
    OR email = 'some_email'
```

It will show you the number of users and the number of emails found.